# Regression with random X

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose we have a standard regression model

$$Y= X\beta + \epsilon$$

with 
$$\epsilon \sim \sigma^2$$
$$X \sim N(\mu,\gamma^2)$$

Are the estimated coefficients the same as if $X$ was fixed?

Is the estimated variance of $\hat{\beta}$ the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we assume that
$$
{\rm E}[\varepsilon | X] = 0,
$$
then the regression coefficients are still calculated as
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY.
$$
The variance of $\hat{\beta}$, however, is no longer the same as the one in the deterministic case since expression
$$
\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1} =: {\rm Var}[\hat{\beta} | X]
$$
is now a random variable. To calculate the overall, unconditional variance of $\hat{\beta}$, we use the rule
$$
{\rm Var}[\hat{\beta}] = {\rm E}[{\rm Var}[\hat{\beta} | X]] + {\rm Var}[{\rm E}[\hat{\beta} | X]].
$$
The landmark book by

... *Greene, W. H. (2011). Econometric Analysis (7th ed). Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall.*

covers the case of stochastic predictors in detail in the earlier chapters.

Answer (score 2):

Regression is the analysis of the *conditional* distribution of a response variable $Y$ given an explanatory variable $X$.  The parameters in the regression model are measuring terms in the expectation of the response variable *conditional on the explanatory variable*, so the model, and the corresponding estimation method, so it will always treat the explanatory variable as a constant.

To the extent that you are interested in the marginal distribution of $Y$ when $X$ is a random variable, that is no longer a question about regression analysis --- it is multivariate analysis.  In that case you formulate a broader model that will its own parameters to describe the marginal distribution of $Y$.